# not calling internal function

Tags: javascript, function

i am just trying to do time counter. when 30 seconds will be over the alert box from another function will popup. i made the code and it's worked for some times too. but now it's not calling the function it only call when i refresh the page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form name="counter"><input type="text" size="8" name="d2"></form> 

<script> 
var milisec = 0
var seconds = localStorage.seconds || 30;
document.counter.d2.value = seconds;

function display() {

    if (milisec <= 0) {
        milisec = 9
        seconds -= 1
    }

    if (seconds <= -1) {
        milisec = 0
        seconds += 1
    } 
    else{

        milisec -= 1

    }
    if(seconds <= 0 && milisec < 1)
    {
        console.log("done");
        localStorage.clear();
        anotherFunction();
    }
    else
    {
         localStorage.seconds = seconds;
    }
    document.counter.d2.value = seconds + "." + milisec;

    if (seconds > 0 || (seconds == 0 && milisec > 0)) {
        setTimeout(display, 100);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}

display();


function anotherFunction()
{
    alert("reached");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`
here is the code.

Comment: In my understanding, its working just fine. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7w6rqmks/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this ones helps you.

```
if(seconds<=0)
{
    throw '';
}
```

put this function before the function.